# JQuery serialize not working, returns nothing

Tags: jquery

I have tried to use the serialize function countless times and have never once been successful. I thought I'd ask and possibly see what I'm doing wrong.

I'm using the latest release of JQuery which is 1.9.1. I can alert from within the function so it's not that JQuery isn't loaded. All I get back after posting the form is an empty console log.

What will it take to get this working?

Here is my HTML

```
  <form id="admin-form" method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" id="test" />
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
  </form>
```

Here is the JQuery

```
  $("#admin-form").on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.post( "/index", $("#admin-form").serialize(),function(data) {

    });
  });
```

Comment: Give your input a `name`: `<input type="text" id="test" name="test" />`

Comment: @PeterMichael, thanks Peter. I was able to find a post that mentioned this very thing. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've been through several posts on this site looking for an answer to this question and I just found it. If anyone else is having this issue, **make sure you've specified the `name` attribute in your elements**. I usually omit this attribute in all my elements and is why `serialize` wasn't working.